# Integrity error while trying to serialize nested object using django rest framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, nested, django-rest-framework

**Model file**

```
class Address(models.Model):
    address_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    address_data = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
```

**Serializer File**

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('address_data')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'address')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        address_data = validated_data.pop('address')
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Address.objects.create(user=user, **address_data)
        return user
```

I have the above code snippet in the model and serializer file.
I am getting a integrity error while serializing and saving the following object.

```
{"name": "John", "address": {"address_data": "some address"}}
```

I am trying to save two objects in 2 tables with a foreign key constraint. The place where I feel its erroring out is 
`user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)` because `address` object is still not created and I am trying to save the `user` object without the `address` reference.

I checked all the django-rest-framework [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations). I am not able to understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: I am getting the following error string `IntegrityError at /api/v1/user/create
null value in column "address_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, John, null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your UserSerializer the model is Address. Shouldn't it be User?

### Edit

Your create method on the UserSerializer should be like this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        address_data = validated_data.pop('address')
        address = Address.objects.create(**address_data)
        validated_data['address'] = address
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Your User has Foreign Key to Address, but you were not passing that on to the User's create method.

Comment: Am sorry it's User only. And not address..it was a typo